# How to change color of a stacked bar plot from a large dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

I have a dataset of 450 variables. When I use ggplot2 to create a stalked bar plot

```
ggplot(mDataSpecies, aes(x = Sites, y = value,fill=variable)) +
geom_bar(stat='identity', show.legend = FALSE)
```

I get bars with a not so readable continuous [color pattern:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aer7c.png)

I am trying to get a plot with a color pattern similar to [this one:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dUGo.pngo)

I tried different color palettes like RColorBrewer but they are not suitable for big datasets.

Comment: Are you asking for suggestions on what color palette you should use? If so, [see this page](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/colorPaletteCheatsheet.pdf) for a breakdown of the R color palettes available

Answer (score 1):

The [link](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/colorPaletteCheatsheet.pdf) provided by @emilliman5 provides some contrasting palettes in the last page, although the largest still contain 12 colors at max. It is possible to get more colors by:

```
colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))(20)
```

This calls up the `RColorBrewer` to produce all 9 colors from the `Set1` palette, and then interpolates to get 20 colors in total. The interpolated colors will not be as contrasting as the original diverging palette, though. Then again, if you require more than 10 categories, is a stacked barplot truly the best choice?